# How to capture query params in Angular app before showing any UI

Tags: angular, url, url-parameters, query-string

I need to capture `queryParam` from URL `http://localhost:4200/?user=123456` before showing any UI in  my Angular application.

Actually I'm using this :

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'params-lab';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('Params = ' + JSON.stringify(params));
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

But in the dev console I'm getting for the first time `Params = {}` and then `Params = {"user":"131245"}`.

This way isn't what I'm expecting because I need to check if params are OK or not to redirect to the correct component like discribed below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for the old good JavaScript solution to avoid any subscription issues :
Here is my code and it works as intended :

```
ngOnInit() {

    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const user = urlParams.get('user');
    const requesterType = urlParams.get('espace');
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In two different ways u can solve this problem

1. Send an additional param as uservalid = true from backend (easy solution but not efficient approach )
2. Implement Route Guard with additional flags, where u can have concrete RBAC our the component.

https://codeburst.io/understanding-angular-guards-347b452e1892

Answer (score 0):

Subscription in constructor will rarely return a value as fast as you want. Thus, introduce a var to keep the parameters:

```
parameters: string = null;
```

Then give it a value inside your constructor:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    if (params) {
        this.parameters = JSON.stringify(params);
        // send parameters to method that will
        // work with parameters, i.e. your logic to load
        // different pages based on parameters value
    }
});
```

You can put some loader content into app.component to be displayed until `parameters` are available through subscription:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!parameters">
    (loading content: text, image, spinner, whatever)
<ng-container>
```

Or just omit any html content.

Answer (score 0):

`ActivatedRoute` gives you information about a route associated with a component that is loaded in an outlet. If you subsribe to the queryParams observable in your root component, you will see each and every change. As far as I understood you use case correctly, this is not what you want. I think you should register a separate component on your target route and put the redirect logic there.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path: '', component: RedirectComponent },
]),
```

and

```
class RedirectComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log('Params = ' + JSON.stringify(params));
      if (/*...*/) {
         // redirect from here
      }
    });
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wjyejt?file=src/app/redirect/redirect.component.ts